# AngularJS - Save password after login in Safari

Tags: javascript, angularjs, safari

I have a form with `ng-submit=""`, so there is no refresh of the page.
I managed to trigger "Save password" notice in Firefox and Chrome, but it doesn't work for Safari.

What I did is that after the form is submitted and login is successful I hide the form (`display:none;`) then I set a timeout with delay of 1 second to show the form again (`display:block;`)

Comment: What do you mean by "I managed to trigger Save password"? Code or explanation please.

Comment: @Arg0n What I did is that after the form is submitted and login is successful I hide the form (display:none;) then I set a timeout with delay of 1 second to show the form again (display:block;)

Comment: How does this answer the question? This is just repeating the text in yours.